# What is the best way to get the number of elements in a PyTables row iterator?

Tags: python, iterator, pytables

My current approach is:

```
rowiter = atable.where(condition)
rowiter_length = max([i for i, row in enumerate(rowiter)])
```

Is there a way to get the length of rowiter without looping through the entire iterator?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's a more efficient way, but you should really just be using `len(rowiter)` instead of that list comp, for two reasons:

1. If the iterator object DOES have a more efficient way of calculating its length, it'll most likely have made it accessible via the `__len__` special method, so you'll get the speedup if it's available.
2. `enumerate` starts at index 0, so your construct will return 1 less than the actual length of the iterator.